# How can I log acpi temperatures?

Tags: 14.04, log, acpi, temperature

I'm trying to debug why my computer randomly shuts down sometimes, and to rule out temperature issues (since I don't think that's the case) I would like to log the output of `acpi -t` somewhere so when it shuts down I can review what happened.

I know of the `lm-sensors` package as talked about in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41794/how-to-monitor-log-server-hardware-temperatures-load), but I'd like to avoid installing another package(s) and simply use the terminal.

I tried using `watch acpi -t >> temp.log`, but the output is all garbled - [temp.log](http://pastebin.com/J0AHPTyG)

How do I log the output of `acpi -t` on intervals correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are console control characters made by `watch` output. You should avoid using `watch` when you need to redirect a command output. Here is a better approach:

```
while sleep 1; do echo `date +"%F %T"` `acpi -t` >> temp.log; done
```